# Reorganize data horizontally on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I reorganize data from:

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B
Fruit      Apple
Fruit      Banana
Fruit      Lemon
Fruit      Mango
Fruit      Orange
Vegetables  Carrots
Vegetables  Potatoes
```

Into this way:

```
COLUMN A   COLUMN B
Fruit      Apple,Banana,Lemon,Mango,Orange
Vegetables  Carrots,Potatoes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel 365

In **C1** enter:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""))
```

In **D1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A:A=C1,B:B,""))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gary! You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2010+, you can use Power Query.

- `Group by` Column1
- Aggregate using the `List.Accumulate` function to concatenate the associated text entries in Column2

1. With the cursor in some cell in your table
   `Data / Get&Transform / From Text/Range`
2. When the PQ UI opens, select `Home / Advanced Editor
3. Record the table name you will see in Line 2, and the Column names in Line 3
4. Paste the MCode below into the window
5. Edit the Table and Column names to match what your table looks like.
6. Close and Load (to new sheet) or to a spot on the existing sheet.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"Grouped", each
            List.Accumulate(Record.Field(_,"Column2"), "", (state, current) => 
                if state = "" then current
                else state & ", " & current)}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron! I really appreciate your help. I tried Gary's answer and it works.